# Wordpress: Iframe not showing video, only iframe text

Tags: wordpress, iframe

Why does my theme display the iframe code, not the video..?

I use this to get the code:

```php
<?php $server = get_post_custom_values("server_one"); echo $server[0]; ?>
```

It does not display the video but the code like this:

```php
iframe width="1080" height="720" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" src="http://videomega.tv/view.php?ref=048052048066112078120100115069069115100120078112066048052048&width=1080&height=720" allowFullScreen></iframe>
```

This is happening with all iframes.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are using WordPress content editor and you are pasting the `iframe` code in `visual mode` instead of `text mode`.